# UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone is for iPod touch too?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

Sorry for stupid question, but I have not found a good answer anywhere.

if I check UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone I get YES for both iPhone and iPod touch?

I mean:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

returns YES for iPad only and portrait for both iPhone and iPod?

I developed an iPhone app, now I'm changing it to universal. It's almost done and I wouldn't like to change all my "if". (i don't have a real iPod touch to test it by myself).

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, iPod touch is treaded as iPhone for this.

Answer (score 2):

This macro is made for mainly distinguish the screen size of iPad and iPhone or iPod.

As iPhone and iPod have same screen size thus are both in Phone category.
So `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` is `YES` for iPhone and iPod 
and is `NO` for iPad.
 
For more you can read [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone).